# How can I write this code so that I do not have to round the logarithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I was doing a programming challenge question where you need to found out if a given number (n) is equal to 3 raised to some exponent(x)

9 is True since 3^x -> 3^3 = 9

10 is False since no x for 3^x is equal to 10

my problem occurred when 243 was entered into my code, which returned a result of 4.999 repeating.

my solution was to simply add a round function, in which I arbitrarily decided on 5 decimal places, this solved the problem.

now another problem occurred when the input was 531440, this returns an x value of 11.999998287222695 which, according to the challenge, was false, but with my code returned a true since I rounded to the fifth decimal place. I then changed my round to 10 decimal places and this fixed the code.

I was wondering if there was a way to implement my solution without having to round, as I'm sure if I plugged in enough numbers eventually another one would need to round past >10 decimal places and cause my code to fail. Please see the code below.

```
import math as math

def isPowerOfThree(n):
    print(math.log(n,3))                                     #this line prints the unrounded log result
    print(round((math.log(n,3)),10))                         #this line prints the rounded result
    return n>0 and round((math.log(n,3)),10).is_integer()

n = 243
print(isPowerOfThree(n))
```

Comment: Did you try any approaches that *don't* involve logarithms? For example, computing powers of 3 sequentially and seeing if you land on or exceed `n`? Or repeatedly dividing by 3 and seeing if there are any remainders before reaching 1?

Comment: Just round to an integer and check if the integer exponent gives the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *'trick'* allowing to avoid problems with chosen precision is to round to an integer and then check if this exponent gives the required result. The code below implements this approach:

```
import math

def isPowerOfThree(N):
    if 3**round(math.log(N,3)) == N:
        return True
    return False

N = 531440 # 243
print(isPowerOfThree(N)) # gives False
```

Another approach will be to check all powers of 3 against the target number:

```
def isPowerOfThree(N):
    x = 1
    while True:
        n = 3**x
        if n == N:
            return True
        elif n > N:
            return False
        x += 1
```

And here an approach detecting directly without the need to run multiple loop runs if a number is not a power of 3:

```
def isPowerOfThree(N):
    while True: 
        N , r = divmod(N, 3)
        if r != 0: 
            return False
        if N == 1:
            return True
```

P.S. the two last approaches provide code to what *Karl Knechtel* mentioned in his comment to the question.